Why is the cylindrical Gaussian surface constructed inside the cylindrical shell? Doesn't it enclose no charges?
I have looked up all the lectures, articles, and stackexchange questions for the last 2 hours and am still having difficulties understanding the cylindrical Gaussian surface constrcuted inside a cynlindrical shell. I wrote by questions in details. I would really really appreciate it if anyone could make things clear. Thank you so much in advance?




Now that I wrote the question I can see what is wrong.... I mixed up the gaussian surface and shell!

The charges reside on the outer surface of the conductor.

If the electric field inside the conductor were as you have drawn them where do they finish?  They have to start on a positive charge and end on a negative charge.


I feel like our understanding of shell is different. This was the point I was confused of many times. Isn't cylindrical shell same and hollow cyliner? Or is it just like a paper bent in a circle shape without thickness?

Yes, I would say that a shell is the limit, in terms of decreasing thickness, of a hollow cylinder.
